# Groovy script in Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, groovy

I am working on some investigation on Gradle Build Plugins, written in Groovy.
I could find the jar files, and locate the plugin code that I have to check. As I am new to the Groovy, I am not able to follow its syntax.

Can some one help me to figure it out. I need to know what does the line do.

```
arrayOfCallSite[0].call(arrayOfCallSite[1].call(target), "java");
```

Comment: if this is from a plugin accessible to the world, then adding that as a reference would really give some context.  other than that, `arrayOfCallsite` holds at least two objects (maybe both a `Closure`); the code gets them by index and calls `call` on them with different arguments.

Comment: This appears to be decompiled Groovy code (not Groovy source code)  - are you sure you are looking at the right stuff?